# Django databse -Defining a relationship to two fields on a different model

Tags: django, django-models

Django database relationship

how do i define a relationship such that a record (product)in one model is related to two unique fields (x, y) on a second model?

Comment: Sounds to me that adding two `ForeignKey`s (the `x` and `y` fields) to the second model would solve your problem. Could you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Django does not support compound primary keys yet. There is a ticket and possible ways to handle it if you want to. 
Django ticket [Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) .
You can have a look into [django-compositekey](https://github.com/dcramer/django-compositepks)
also i can find a app you can take a look into this also [simone/django-compositekey](https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey)